# Аналог тега map для HTML5 canvas

Tags: canvas, html5

Есть ли возможность средствами только канваса задавать активную области область на изображении подобно HTML-тегу `<map>`? Через SVG тоже не желательно.

Answer (score 6):

Для тех, кто набрел на вопрос через поиск, - возможные решения.

1. Создать на скрытом канвасе проекцию требуемого объекта, “выкрасить” её в определённый цвет. Затем берём координаты на видимом канвасе и смотрим данные о цвете точки с этими координаты на скрытом (getImageData) и если полученное - цвет нужной проекции, то мы навели мышку на объект. Подмогой для создания проекции может послужить глобальное свойство globalCompositeOperation. В цвете проекции можно задавать код объекта, что удобно при проецирование нескольких объектов.
2. Так же нахождение точки на фигуре можно рассчитать математически. Подборка ссылок:

   - [Collision Detection and Response](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) (перевод [Урок: базовые алгоритмы определения столкновений](http://noregret.org/tutor/n/collision/))
   - [О прямоугольных координатах и гексагональных сетках](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147082/)
   - [Polygon triangulation: decomposition of a polygon into triangles with AS3](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/06/27/polygon-triangulation-decomposition-of-a-polygon-into-triangles-with-as3/)
   - [Algorithm to determine if a point is inside a triangle with mathematics (no hit test involved)](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/06/18/algorithm-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-triangle-with-mathematics-no-hit-test-involved/)

Answer (score 1):

Средствами канваса не получится, но можно попробовать приобщить к этому делу js.

Результат можно посмотреть [здесь](http://theshock.github.com/cf/index.html).

Comment: Благодарю. Но фишка заключалась в том, чтоб обойтись без сложных  расчетов, задавая при этом произвольные фигуры. В итоге решили плюнуть и использовать html.

Для тех кто набрел на вопрос через поиск - возможные решения:
1.Создать на скрытом канвасе проекцию требуемого объекта, “выкрасить” её в определённый цвет. Затем берём координаты на видимом канвасе и смотрим данные о цвете точки с этими координаты на скрытом (getImageData) и если полученное - цвет нужной проекции то мы навели мышку на объект. Подмогой для создания проекции может послужить глобальное свойство globalCompositeOperation.

Comment: ок, понятно